# How to resolve "expected ';' before '{' token" in C?

Tags: c, compilation, compiler-errors, runtime-compilation

I created a program to print the roman equivalent of a year, but my program shows a compilation error. My program says:

> 33    4   C:\Users\ABC\Desktop\c.c    [Error] expected ';' before '{' token

Here is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
    int a,rom;
    printf("Enter the year.");
    scanf("%d",&a);
    rom=reverse(a);
    printf("Roman equivalent of %d is:",a);
}
reverse(int a)
{
    int i,rev=0,rem;
    for(i=a;i>0;i=i/10)
    {
        rem=i%10;
        rev=rev*10+rem;
    }
    roman(a);
}
roman(int a)
{
    int c=0,i,j,k,l,m;
    for(i=a;i>0;i=i/10)
    {
        m=i%10;
        for(j=1;j>0;j--)
        {
            if(c==0)
            {
                printf("m\n");
            }
            elseif(c==1)
            {
                printf("d\n");
                for(l=m-5;l>0;l--)
                    printf("c");
                printf("\n");
            }
            elseif(c==2)
            {
                printf("l\n");
                for(l=m-5;l>0;l--)
                {
                    printf("x");
                }
                printf("\n");
            }
            elseif(c==3)
            {
                printf("v\n");
                for(l=m-5;l>0;l--)
                {
                    printf("i");
                }
                printf("\n");
            }
        }
        c++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you read the errors the compiler gave you ?

Comment: yes the gcc compiler says:
c.c:33:4: error expected ';' before '{' token
{

Comment: Admittedly, the error message is a bit misleading...

Comment: WOW!  A misleading compiler error message....  :)

Comment: Additionally, use `void` before the function headers, except `main` and `int` before `main`. Also, declare the function before `main`. Isn't your compiler yelling at you with all these warnings? If not, enable warnings. If yes, pay heed to them.

Comment: In addition the other comments: you should compiler with all warnings enabled.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use `else if` instead of `elseif`.

Comment: Thanks i'm so stupid

Comment: @SnehilGupta happens to all of us..relax :)

Answer (score 3):

You have missed a space in your `else if`.. its not `elseif` but `else if`

Answer (score 2):

it is typo error use else if instead of elseif

```
            if(c==0)
            {
                printf("m\n");
            }
            else if(c==1)
            {
                printf("d\n");
                for(l=m-5;l>0;l--)
                    printf("c");
                printf("\n");
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no `elseif` in C. You must write `else if` (2 separate words).

But admittedly the error message is somewhat misleading, but at a second look it's actually quite normal.

Explanation:

```
if(c==0)
{
  printf("m\n");
}
elseif(c==1)
{
   ...
}
```

The compiler supposes `elseif` is the name of some function taking an `int` as argument, therefore it expects a `;` after the closing parenthesis of the `elseif`;

This is what the compiler thinks you want:

```
if (...)           
{
  printf("m\n");     // normal conditional statement
}

elseif(c==1) ;       // call to some function elseif

{                    // unconditional {} block
   ...
}
```

If you had compiled with all warnings enabled, the compiler would have issued a warning such as

> Implicit function declaration of 'elseif'